# cannot use $(this) in $.each function inside jquery ui sortable event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, each

I'm unable to grab $(this) from inside the each.  I'm trying to reset the css of the table after a row has been moved. "#newTaskBody" is the id of the tbody. ".newProjectTask" is the class of the s.

```
// make the table sortable;
$("#newTaskBody").sortable({
    stop: function() {
        var counter = 0;
        $.each(".newProjectTask", function() {
            console.log(this.id);
            if(counter == 0)
            {
                $(this).removeClass("even odd");
                $(this).addClass("even");
                counter = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass("even odd");
                $(this).addClass("odd");
                counter = 0;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

the console.log(this.id); returns undefined 15 times although I'm testing with 4 rows.  I've tried 'stop', 'update' and 'change' events.

Comment: @DominicGreen lol **no**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pass `string` i.e. `".newProjectTask"` instead of elements having class newProjectTask to each function. Each iteration gives `you character of the string`,To see whats happening what going on check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/j5Z4x/)

Change

```
$.each(".newProjectTask", function() {
```

To

```
$.each($(".newProjectTask"), function() {
```

This is how you will get the elements by each

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/j5Z4x/1/)**

```
<div id="div1" class="newProjectTask" > div1 </div>
<div id="div1"  class="newProjectTask" > div2 </div>
<div id="div1"  class="newProjectTask" > div3 </div>


​$.each($(".newProjectTask"), function() {
    alert(this.id)
})
```

Its **better to use other version of each** i.e. `$('.newProjectTask').each(` instead on one you used.​

```
$(".newProjectTask").each( function() {
    alert(this.id)
})
```

Comment: or just `$('.newProjectTask').each(function(){...});`

Comment: Thanks @Neal, Yes neal thats another way to do that.

Comment: That is the way according to the DOCs

Comment: Good work @Adil! I wish I would have posted this 2 hours ago ;)

Comment: and @Neal.  I used the correct method.  Not sure why that slipped my mind.  Thanks again guys!!

Comment: `$.each()` and `$('.class').each()` are two different functions and therefore not comparable in a 'which way is correct' argument. I do agree with you that in this context it is better to use the latter. Bear in mind that $.each can iterate over arrays, maps and objects. `.each` will iterate over only what the jQuery object contains.

Comment: Yes here its better to use $('selector').each(), Thanks Neal and @David Barker

Comment: On the JSFiddle, all the `<div>` have the same `id`, the alert shows `div1` three times. Can you please change this?